# Using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$, prove that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,2)} (xy^2+\frac{3}{x})=13$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I started working on factoring $|xy^2+\frac{3}{x}-13|$ and got to $|xy^2-12-\frac{x-3}{x}|$. I have to get to $(y-2)$ somehow, but am confused how to get that from $xy^2-12$. Can anyone give even a slight hint? :)

Comment: 1st: why do you need to "use epsilon-delta"? (whatever that means) ; 2nd: why are you trying to factorize?

Comment: It was given to us as homework. The epsilon-delta definition states that $\lim_{x,y \to 3,2} xy^2+\frac{3}{x}=13 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2}<\delta \Rightarrow |xy^2+\frac{3}{x}-13|<\varepsilon$.           If i could factor $|xy^2+\frac{3}{x}-13|$ so it included $(x-3)$ and $(y-2)$, I could go from there and prove the limit.

Comment: Let's assume you managed to factorize and now have something like xy²+3/x-13=(x-3)(y-2)f(x,y), with f being a two-variables function. Would that help you? If not, then factorizing is not what you want, here.

Is there anything else that could help you in your textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be fixed.

We can write

\begin{align}
\big|xy^2+\frac 3x-13\big| &= \big|xy^2-3\cdot2^2+\frac3x-1\big| =\\[1.5ex]
&= \big|(x-3)\,4+x(y^2-2^2)+\frac {3-x}x\big|\leq\\[1.5ex]
&\leq \big|x-3\big|\,4+\big|x\big|\cdot\big|y-2\big|\cdot\big|y+2\big|+\frac{\big|3-x\big|}{\big|x\big|}\leq\ldots\\[1.5ex]
\end{align}
$\Big[$Because $(x,y)$ converges to $(3,2)$, we can suppose that $2\leq x\leq 4,\quad 1\leq y\leq 3$, i.e. $(x,y)$ belongs to the closed square $S\Big((3,2),1\Big)$ centered in$(3,2)$ with half-side $1\Big]$
\begin{align}
\phantom{ll}\ldots&\leq\big|x-3\big|\,4+4\,\big|y-2\big|\,5+\frac12\,\big|3-x\big|=\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac92\,\big|x-3\big|+20\,\big|y-2\big|\leq\\[1.5ex]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\leq 20\Big(\big|x-3\big|+\big|y-2\big|\Big)\leq\ldots\\[1.5ex]
\end{align}
$\bigg[$ By using that $\;a,b\in\mathbb R \implies a+b\leq\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\bigg]$
\begin{align}
\phantom{l}\ldots&\leq 20\,\sqrt2\,\sqrt{\big|x-3\big|^2+\big|y-2\big|^2}\leq\varepsilon
\end{align}

when

$$ (x,y)\in B\Big((3,2), \frac{\varepsilon}{20\sqrt2}\Big)\cap S\Big((3,2),1\Big), $$

where $B\Big((\xi,\eta),r\Big)$ denote the closed disk centered in $(\xi,\eta)$ and with radius $r$.

Hence a possible choice for $\delta$ is

$$\delta=\min\Big(\frac\varepsilon{20\sqrt2},1\Big). $$

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way to factor this, but you don't need to!
By the sum limit law, we have that
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (3,2)} (xy^2+\frac{3}{x}) = \lim_{(x,y)\to (3,2)} xy^2 + \lim_{(x,y)\to (3,2)} \frac{3}{x}.$
From here, the $\epsilon- \delta $ argument should be a little easier. For the $xy^2$ limit, the factoring approach should work, for the $\frac{3}{x}$ limit, consider
$\left\lvert \frac{3}{x}-\frac{3}{3}, \right\rvert,$
combine fractions and note that $1/x>1/2$ for $x$ close enough to $3$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!